# How to add array of text and images in Segmentio in swift

Tags: ios, swift, segment, segment-io

I am using [segmentio](https://github.com/Yalantis/Segmentio) pod for segment with image and text, I have added pod in project and added view in storyboard and assign Segmentio class name and import Segmentio.

Here how to add array of text and images in segmentio

i have tried like below:

```
 import UIKit
 import Segmentio
 class EventsDashboardViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var segmentioView: Segmentio!

//var swipeMenuArray: NSMutableArray = []
var content = [SegmentioItem]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

 segmentioView.setup(
    content: [SegmentioItem],
    style: SegmentioStyle,
    options: SegmentioOptions?
)

    
    let tornadoItem = SegmentioItem(
        (title: "Alert",
        image: UIImage(named: "img1")),
        (title: "Message",
        image: UIImage(named: "img2")),
        (title: "Stared",
        image: UIImage(named: "img3"))
    )
    content.append(tornadoItem)

 }

 }
```

**errors**:

> Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'
>
> Missing argument labels 'title:image:selectedImage:' in call
>
> Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this pod, but I think `SegmentioItem` isn't type array, it looks like item of array, try this for one item:

```
let tornadoItem1 = SegmentioItem(title: "Alert", image: UIImage(named: "img1"))
content.append(tornadoItem1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid Swift. The part that says

```
segmentioView.setup(
    content: [SegmentioItem],
    style: SegmentioStyle,
    options: SegmentioOptions?
)
```

is not valid. It looks like a combination of a function call and a function definition.

I can see that the documentation for Segmentio is not very clear and also includes this invalid code.

Correct usage could be something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  content.append(SegmentioItem(title: "Alert", image: UIImage(named: "img1"))
  content.append(SegmentioItem(title: "Message", image: UIImage(named: "img2"))
  content.append(SegmentioItem(title: "Stared", image: UIImage(named: "img3"))

  segmentioView.setup(
    content: content,
    style: .imageBeforeLabel,
    options: nil
  )
}
```

I do not know Segmentio so this might not be 100 % correct.